# How do i save a custom NSObject class to file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

I tried:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];

    BOOL success = [data writeToFile:entryPath atomically:YES];
```

But for whatever reason, it crashed with this error:

```
2012-03-24 20:06:13.550 Journal[1348:707] -[JEntry encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25d1a0
2012-03-24 20:06:13.553 Journal[1348:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JEntry encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25d1a0'
```

How else do i save an NSObject subclass to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *implement* `encodeWithCoder:` in your `JEntry` class if you want `NSArchiver` to work.  You will probably want `initWithCoder:`, too, so that you can deserialize later.

Read the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) to get started.